When was the last time a Canadian hockey team reached the third round of the Stanley Cup finals?
When was the last time a Canadian team reached the third round of the Stanley Cup finals?

In the current format, reaching third round means playing in the conference finals.1 There is a Wikipedia article listing the NHL conference finals. You can see that in 2022 Edmonton Oilers
played in Western Conference final. (They lost to Colorado Avalanche.)
In the current season, Vancouver Canucks are facing Edmonton Oilers in second round - so one of these two teams will certainly play in the conference finals.

1There was a relatively recent exception - 2021 Stanley Cup playoffs were played in four divisions with no conferences. This was due to the COVID-19 pandemic.
